# Context dependent cross reference formatting

Tags: cross-referencing

I'd like to format my equations so that within any chapter, the label generated is

> (\thesection.\theequation)   1+1 =2

(without chapter number).

A cross-reference within a given chapter would be just these two numbers, but a reference to the same equation from a different chapter would yield:

> (chapter.section.equation)

I've seen this done (the books by Hairer, Wanner et cie.)  but cannot find the right information.

I intended to start from this

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on,leqno,10pt,notitlepage,abstracton]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
    \label{cha:first}

\section{FA}
\label{sec:fa}
\begin{equation}
  x + x = 2x
\end{equation}

\section{FB}
\label{sec:fa}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  x + b = a
\end{equation}

\chapter{Second}
\label{cha:second}

\section{SA}
\label{sec:sa}

See Eqn.~\eqref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:2}
  e^{i\beta}
\end{equation}

Eqn.~\eqref{eq:2} is Euler's favorite: it has all the important constants
in it. 
\section{b}
\label{sec:b}
From Eqn.~\eqref{eq:1}, we cannot derive Eqn.~\eqref{eq:2}. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide the community with a base template of your document structure, preferably in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. So much so that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly something that you're working with... no `\include`, not `\input`, just `\usepackage` and some dummy text. Follow the link provided to get a flavour of what should/not be included.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? What about [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start using [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s "property lists":

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{relrefprops}
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\zref@newprop{chapeqnum}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\zref@newprop{eqnum}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\zref@addprops{relrefprops}{chapter,chapeqnum,eqnum}

% Mark a possible "relative label"
\newcommand{\releqlabel}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{relrefprops}%
}
% Use a "relative label" in a reference
\newcommand{\releqref}[1]{%
  \mbox{(%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=\zref@extractdefault{#1}{chapter}{0}
    \zref@extract{#1}{eqnum}% In same chapter
  \else
    \zref@extract{#1}{chapeqnum}% In different chapter
  \fi
  )}%
  \zref@refused{#1}% Reference has been used
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{4}% Just for this example
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{section}{8}% Just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{3}% Just for this example
\section{A section}
See \releqref{eq:f} and \releqref{eq:g}.
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \releqlabel{eq:f}
\end{equation}

{\let\clearpage\relax% Just for this example
\setcounter{chapter}{7}% Just for this example
\chapter{Another chapter}
}\setcounter{section}{5}% Just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{9}% Just for this example
\section{Another section}
See \releqref{eq:f} and \releqref{eq:g}.
\begin{equation}
  g(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \delta \releqlabel{eq:g}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`\releqlabel` sets a `label` for an `eq`uation that may require a `rel`ative reference later. Similarly, `\releqref` is used to `ref`erence an `eq`uation that may be `rel`ative to the current chapter.

`zref` is compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref), so this approach could be extended to include that.

Comment: That's very close except for the tag formatting.  My edits in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few minor tweaks and now, this is it.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on,leqno,10pt,notitlepage,abstracton]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref}


\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}


\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{relrefprops}
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\zref@newprop{section}{\arabic{section}}
\zref@newprop{chapeqnum}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\zref@newprop{eqnum}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\zref@addprops{relrefprops}{chapter,chapeqnum,eqnum,section}

% Mark a possible "relative label"
\newcommand{\releqlabel}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{relrefprops}%
}
% Use a "relative label" in a reference
\newcommand{\releqref}[1]{%
  \mbox{(%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=\zref@extractdefault{#1}{chapter}{0}
    \zref@extract{#1}{eqnum}% In same chapter
  \else
    \zref@extract{#1}{chapeqnum}% In different chapter
  \fi
  )}%
  \zref@refused{#1}% Reference has been used
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{4}% Just for this example
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{section}{8}% Just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{3}% Just for this example
\section{A section}
See \releqref{eq:f} and \releqref{eq:g}.
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \releqlabel{eq:f}
\end{equation}

{\let\clearpage\relax% Just for this example
\setcounter{chapter}{7}% Just for this example
\chapter{Another chapter}
}\setcounter{section}{5}% Just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{9}% Just for this example
\section{Another section}
See \releqref{eq:f} and \releqref{eq:g}.
\begin{equation}
  g(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \delta \releqlabel{eq:g}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```